# How to format the navigation menu in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I have made my own theme from the RWD theme. Now, as seen in the first pic below, my sub-menus overlap. I do not want this. I want it to be like the second pic so the sub-menu nicely aligns to the right with the parent element.

[image: Current nav menu]

What I am after:

[image: What I desire]

Comment: it's css issue only share your url i will tell

Comment: I gathered as much. Sorry the site is on a local server not live on the internet.